# integrate Angular 7 feature module to be used by C# RAZOR form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular

I developed a large Angular 7 project with many featured modules like the following

```js
/myProject
  /src
   /feature1
   /feature2
   /feature3
   /shared
```

In some ASP.Net MVC forms, I need to reuse the feature2 from the Angular 7 project. Is it possible to conditionally build the project so that only feature2 is compiled? I would like to have the source code maintained in the Angular project, and not to copy the code into the MVC projects.  In AngularJs (1x) I could use <div ng-include /> the Angular template but I don't know how to do this in Angular 7.  Thanks.

Comment: took me a few reads to understand what you're asking. [Angular Elements](https://angular.io/guide/elements) is what you're after. heres a [small tut on the subject](https://medium.com/@kitson.mac/wrapping-an-angular-app-in-a-custom-element-web-component-angular-element-in-4-simple-steps-ded3554e9006)

Comment: it looks that the desired component needs to be in a separate ng project because it needs a separate appModule.  Is it possible to have one codebase but with conditional compilation, so that only the desired component and dependencies are compiled into a distributable js.  Thanks.